# How can I skip line with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a command like this:

```
tac $log | awk -v pattern="test" '$9 ~ pattern {print; exit}'
```

It shows me the last line in which `$9` contains `test` text.

Like this:

```
Thu Mar 26 20:21:38 2015 1 10.8.0.22 94 /home/xxxyyy/zzz_test_223123.txt b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 26 20:21:39 2015 1 10.8.0.22 94 /home/SAVED/zzz_test_123123.txt b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 26 20:21:40 2015 1 10.8.0.22 94 /home/xxxyyy/zzz_test_123123.txt b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 26 20:21:41 2015 1 10.8.0.22 94 /home/SAVED/zzz_test_123124.txt b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
```

-- >

```
Thu Mar 26 20:21:41 2015 1 10.8.0.22 94 /home/SAVED/zzz_test_123124.txt b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
```

This command shows me the last line. But I need to pass if line have `SAVED`. So I need to show like this:

```
Thu Mar 26 20:21:40 2015 1 10.8.0.22 94 /home/xxxyyy/zzz_test_123123.txt b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It is unclear what your intentions are, what do you mean if the line has saved ?

Comment: Mean "saved" word. If $9 have "saved" word, skip it.

Comment: So you want to show the last line that has test but not saved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another condition `!~` to prevent this second pattern to be matched (I use `pattern2` to make it more generic, of course you can hardcode `SAVED` there):

```
$9 ~ pattern && $9 !~ pattern2
```

All together:

```
$ awk -v pattern="test" -v pattern2="SAVED" '$9 ~ pattern && $9 !~ pattern2 {print; exit}'
Thu Mar 26 20:21:40 2015 1 10.8.0.22 94 /home/xxxyyy/zzz_test_123123.txt b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
```

Answer (score 10):

To skip a line, you can match it, and use the `next` command.

```
$9 ~ /SAVED/ { next }
$9 ~ /\.txt$/ { print; exit }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use !~ to test if a line doesn't match a pattern.

```
awk -v pattern="test" $9 ~ pattern && $9 !~ /SAVED/ { print; exit; }
```